# react-datepicker, issues disabling a specific Date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-datepicker

I am using react-datepicker for date and calendar implementation , It works fine I have integrated the component successfully, but facing one issue in making the default date disabled. I am using the below code.

```
<DatePicker customInput={<ExampleCustomInput />} className="w-dtsr-date-picker"
  selected={this.state.startDate}  //called when the date is clicked
  onChange={this.handleChange}    //called only when the value is chnaged
  monthsShown={2}     //number of months to be shown
  minDate={this.props.dateProps.minDate}  //min days to be shown in the calendar
  maxDate={this.props.dateProps.maxDate}  //max days to be shown in the calendar
  onChangeRaw={this.handleDateChangeRaw}  //preventing the user from manually entering the dates or text in the input text box
/>
```

by default say I want to disable 4/25/2019 , I am not able to do that, I see the component has a property called **dayClassName** , Have anyone used that , I am not sure how to pass the date and apply css to that specific date.

This is what i found in one of the examples -

```
dayClassName={date => getDate(date) < Math.random() * 31 ? 'random' : undefined}
```

It did not work for me , not sure how to disable this specific date (4/25/2019), any help on this.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the `dayClassName` prop to disable a specific date and pass a CSS class of your creation that disables user clicks. `dayClassName` returns a JS date so you'll have to compare it to the date you want to disable and then pass the disabled CSS classname if it's `true`

Example:

**Prop:**

```
dayClassName={date => date.getTime() === new Date('04/25/2019').getTime() ? 'disabled-date' : undefined}
```

**CSS:**

```
.disabled-date {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: can you post what datepicker component you have used here?

Comment: My answer is based on the [react-datepicker](https://reactdatepicker.com/) project using the included `DatePicker` component.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the props

```
dayPickerProps={{
       disabledDays={[
            new Date(2017, 3, 12),
            new Date(2017, 3, 2)
          ]}
}}
```

or by directly using the prop as

```
disabledDays={[
        new Date(2017, 3, 12),
        new Date(2017, 3, 2)
    ]}
```

Edit: sorry mis-read DatePicker as DayPicker.
the above applies for DayPicker component.

Edit 2 : 
As per [documentation](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-17) have you tried with prop

```
excludeDates={[new Date(), subDays(new Date(), 1)]}
```

Comment: how we can disable all Sunday, all Tuesday ?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63070975, you customise the function as needed.