# how to disable all the Sundays and array of specific days in ant design date picker

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, antd

following code disabled all the previous dates including today, but I want to disable all the Sundays and array of specific days in ant design date picker.

```
< DatePicker size = "large"
  format = "DD/MM/YYYY"
  nChange = {
    this.onDate1Change
  }
  disabledDate = {
    current => {
      return current && current < moment().endOf('day');
    }
  }
/>
```

---

Comment: Because your are a new contributor, please have a look at [why vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To start we have a look at antd's Datepicker [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/yjegy) in the depending [docs](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/#components-date-picker-demo-disabled-date).

1. Disable all Sundays

We use the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) lib to check the days and disable all sundays (here it is the first == zero).

E.g.:

```
function disabledDate(current) {
  // Can not select sundays and predfined days
  return moment(current).day() === 0 
}
```

2. Disable specific days

First we define an array of our dates and then check if a converted day is in our disabled array.

```
const disabledDates = ["2020-07-21", "2020-07-23"];

function disabledDate(current) {
  // Can not select Sundays and predefined days
  return disabledDates.find(date => date === moment(current).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
}
```

3. Putting all together

Now we can combine both solutions. A working example can be found in [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-goldberg-1n30p?file=/index.js).

E.g.:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import moment from "moment";
import { DatePicker } from "antd";

const disabledDates = ["2020-07-21", "2020-07-23"];

function disabledDate(current) {
  // Can not select Sundays and predefined days
  return (
    moment(current).day() === 0 ||
    disabledDates.find(date => date === moment(current).format("YYYY-MM-DD"))
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <>
    <DatePicker
      format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
      disabledDate={disabledDate}
      showTime={{ defaultValue: moment("00:00:00", "HH:mm:ss") }}
    />
  </>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the "Moment" library, you can do as I did:

```
const disabledDate = (current) => {
    return (
        current < Date.now() ||
        (new Date(current).getDay() === 0 ||
        new Date(current).getDay() === 6)
    );
};
```